# How to merge binary data by certain group(s) in R

Tags: group-by, merge, binary

I'm looking at the presence/absence of earthworm species in certain forest types, here is a small snippet of my data...

| Site | Forest Type | Date | A. sp | A. rosea | A. tuberculata | D. octaedra | L. sp | L. rubellus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | MH | 6/17/2022 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 27 | FD | 6/21/2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 68 | MH | 6/21/2022 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 66 | FD | 7/6/2022 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

What I would like to do is group all my data by forest type (so either FD or MH) and for the binary data transfer in a way that anytime a certain species was found in either forest, it has a 1. (or a 0 if that species was never found in that forest type)

so something like this...(based off the snippet I proved above)

| Forest Type | A. sp | A. rosea | A. tuberculata | D. octaedra | L. sp | L. rubellus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| FD | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

I've tried just running a group_by(Forest.Type) but it didn't change by data at all. I assume I have to add something to it, but I'm unsure what.